# convert weird characters to english characters with php

Tags: php, data-conversion

i have string "à¦•à¦¾à¦²à§‡à¦° à¦•à¦£à§à¦". I need to convert all the characters of this string into english characters and numbers. I need to do it in php. Is it possible? The code i  currently have isn't working properly. it just just giving me a string consisting of only question marks. the code is given below -

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ASCII', 'utf-8');
echo $str;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: any conversion will do? ... try base64 or bin2hex

Comment: Which encoding is that (string of the question)?

Comment: @deviantfan, i am sorry but i don't know. how can i find which encoding it is? my guess is utf-8. but i am not sure.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, can you please elaborate your answer, how can i convert it?

Comment: It is not UTF8 (at least no normal text in UTF8). But...if we assume that it is a normal text, i don´t know any possible encoding. So, strictly speaking, there is no way to determine the encoding to given data. You just have to know it.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, I am sorry but base64 conversion won't do as it converts not text into another string. Is there any other way around?

Comment: What DarkSquirrel meant, that you can take the hex code of the bytes or something like that, then you would have english characters (and numbers). But that´s probably not what you want.<br>Once again to the encoding: Do you have an idea what the content could be?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44244/discussion-between-eddard-stark-and-deviantfan)